# iOS - Any Customized UI for UITextField and UILabel

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextfield, uilabel

Here is a UI for iOS I am looking for:

In a view of my application for iOS, 
a user is asked to fill out all underline blanks in not fixed number of distinct questions of the following form(for example):

> My ID is _ _ _ _ and telephone number is _ _ _ - _ _ _ _.

Since questions are not fixed, UIText is not enough to use for my requirement. I spent three days on finding proper UI control and view but did not find it.

Is there any UI control and view for my requirement? 
If not, I need to build some my own UI control and view using UIKit. Could you recommend any good reference for building customized UI using UIKit? Any suggestion would be very welcomed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can look this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5). Here he has covered many UI Controls and their customizations